# what is type BYTE mean in c language?

Tags: c

`BYTE buffer`

what is type `BYTE` mean?

I saw is using on `buffer`.

I had been search on google, but no answer.

Comment: `BYTE` is either a `define` or a `typedef`.  Can you provide this?

Comment: There is no type called byte in C. It is probably unsigned char or uint8_t from stdint.h

Comment: my guess is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types

Comment: @ungfranco BYTE means nothing in C because there is no such an entity defined in the C Standard.:) It can have a meaning in some user-defined application.

Comment: there is no `BYTE` in the C language. It means : "a compile error" unless you give it some meaning yourself. https://godbolt.org/z/z56T3C

Comment: `BYTE,WORD,DWORD,QWORD` are basic unsigned integer datatypes (leftover from assembly languages). some C/C++ compilers have them natively supported like for example ancient Turbo C/Cpp/Pascal ... to My knowledge modern compilers does not recognize it (appart from Borland/Embarcadero ones) however libraries might have them defined as typedefs or macros for compatibility reasons one such example is `Windows.h` ... Byte is usually 8bit `unsigned char` ... beware of careless combining/using  `char` and `BYTE` especially in file format decoders/encoders might lead to problems due to overflow ...

Answer (score 2):

The C standard does not even mention it, so the short answer is: nothing.

Some C compilers use it. For instance Microsofts. There it is defined like this:

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
```

Answer (score 2):

The C language definition doesn't specify a `BYTE` type, so it depends on the specific compiler or library you are using.

`BYTE` is *most likely* a `typedef` name for `unsigned char` (or `uint8_t` for newer implementations that support `stdint.h`):

```
typedef unsigned char BYTE;
```

Check your compiler's documentation.